# How to find the max 3 values count of the particular column using group_by in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

data:

```
   C  J        SD
 1: H  A       1230
 2: H  B       1000
 3: H  C        123
 4: H  D      12345
 5: H  E       4321
 6: P  C        234
 7: P  D         23
 8: P  E        587
 9: P  F        543
```

Required output:

```
 C  J        SD
1.H  D      12345
2.H  E       4321
3.H  A       1230
4.P  E        587
5.P  F        543
6.P  C        234
```

I have tried;

```
data %>% arrange(desc(`SD`)) %>% group_by( `C` ,`J`) %>%  top_n(3)
```

but not getting desired output.

Is any another way or I'm going wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group only by `C` value

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%  group_by(C) %>%  top_n(3, SD)
```

Also `top_n` is now superseded with `slice_max`/`slice_min` which can be used as -

```
data %>%  
  group_by(C) %>%  
  slice_max(SD, n = 3) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks !!!, @Ronak Shah , its workout for me

Answer (score 1):

To get exactly what you want.

`Df <- Df %>%arrange(desc(SD))%>%arrange(C) %>%group_by(C) %>%  top_n(3)`

Comment: Thanks !!!, @Daman deep , its workout for me